Simple Android Timer App runs until API33 but crashes with API34 or 35
I wrote a simple android app in Android Studio. It shows a button that starts a timer that plays a sound every X minutes until stopped with another button.
For the alarm I use
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.getApplicationContext(), myRequestCode, myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, 3000, reminderRate, pendingIntent);

I also use the following code to start a foreground service that ran fine up to API33 - but if I test it with the following line on API34 or API35 it will crash.
startForegroundService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyService.class));

Can anyone put me on the right track?
